Pressure gradient relation with flow direction in a pump volute
I am new to turbomachinery and currently studying pump concepts. As far as I know, in a typical centrifugal pump, the impeller imparts energy to the fluid by increasing its angular velocity. This angular kinetic energy is then converted into pressure energy in the volute as the fluid flows through a duct with an increasing cross-sectional area. In this case, can we say that the pressure gradient in the volute acts in opposition to the direction of fluid flow?
